# Prolog not unique elements in predicate call

Tags: prolog

In my Prolog script, I have defined:

```
mother(X,Y) :-
    parent_of(X,Y),
    female(X).
```

I then want to know if there are any mothers with more than two children, so I run:

```
mother(X,Y), mother(X,Z)
```

With the result:

```
X = pam,
Y = M, M = bob
```

Which has left me quite baffled.... I figured that if I add

```
not(Y = Z)
```

This will fix it, but am unsure as to why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute a query like

```
mother(X,Y).
```

The result would bring back mothers that have two children as well.

So if your database was something like

```
female(maria).
female(irini).
parent_of(maria,nick).
parent_of(maria,dario).
parent_of(irini,dewey).
```

and you executed the `mother(X,Y).` query, the result would bring back

```
1 ?- mother(X,Y).
X = maria,
Y = nick ;
X = maria,
Y = dario ;
X = irini,
Y = dewey.
```

So your result would have the mother (maria) that has two children.

If you **only** want a mother with two children, you should modify your `mother` query as:

```
mother(X,Y) :-
    parent_of(X,Y),
    parent_of(X,M),
    Y \= M,
    female(X).
```

The result of this query would be:

```
3 ?- mother(X,Y).
X = maria,
Y = nick ;
X = maria,
Y = dario ;
false.
```

(*false* means that Prolog did't find any more results).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you assumed that variables with different names can't have the same value. That's not true. You have to specify this explicitly (like in mathematics, for example, - variable X can have the same value as a different variable Y, unless you explicitly specify the opposite).